# USB 3.0 port on external hard drive is broken

Tags: usb-3, repair

The USB micro B port on my external hard drive — it’s a WD external hard drive and it’s data is encrypted — is broken.

- Pin 1: vbus
- Pin 2: d-
- Pin 3: d+

When I try to connect with PC it doesn’t connect. But when I apply pressure it glows but doesn’t blink and the hard disk drive not spinning.

The hard disk drive also doesn’t show up.

Could this be because of insufficient power supply or there is a problem with hard disk drive? Will Replacing the pins or the USB micro B port solve the problem?

Comment: Best solution is to not waste time with the specifics of the USB micro B port and just buy a new external enclosure that can fit the drive and remove the drive from the current enclosure and place it in a new one. USB 3.0 external enclosures are pretty cheap; less than $10 U.S. in many cases. A better investment than repairing a damaged port.

Comment: @JakeGould it's WD external hard disk and all of it's data are encrypted.

Comment: Unless the encryption is via the enclosure itself — very doubtful — you can just put it in a new enclosure and the system will recognize it and work as expected. I have encrypted external drives I have swapped out from one enclosure to another in macOS and all works fine.

Comment: @JakeGould So you're telling that the bios need not to be the same?

Comment: Was the HDD sold as a drive that had encryption built in? If not, just reshell the HDD with a caddy

Comment: @user568963 There’s no BIOS on an external hard drive. 99% of the consumer encryption solutions out there are software or OS based and the drive itself can be connected via anything. If your WD drive came with software I am fairly confident you can just do what I described — remove the drive from the enclosure, put it in a new one and there you go — and all should be fine. All that needs to happen is the drive to be connected and mounted; the OS or software does the rest.

Comment: What exact model WD drive do you have?

Comment: @MMM WD my passport 4tb external Hdd

Comment: @user568963 Just checked the specs and it says, “Password protection with hardware encryption.” So I would see if you can contact Western Digital and have them repair it.